# Missing Functions in Driver - Selenium & Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Not sure why but a lot of functions are missing for me when I try to use find_element_

For example,

```
driver.find_element
```

does not produce any other functions in VSCode. All of my imports are fine too:

```
from tkinter import *
from pathlib import Path
import webbrowser
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

What am I doing wrong? Tried looking to see if anyone has a similar problem but found nothing. I also read the Selenium documentation, still nothing. Really appreciate any help.

My Chromedriver and version of selenium are both up to date as well.

Comment: Please include your code and any errors as text and not as images.  Images placed on external sites (imgur.com..etc) could be deleted making your post completely useless to others.

Comment: @ewokx Gotcha, just updated it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to ChatGPT, it turns out that newer versions of Selenium the functions find_element_by_id and find_elements_by_id have been replaced with more general methods: find_element and find_elements, respectively.

Here is how it would look now:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# ...

element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'element_id')
```

SHOUTOUT TO CHATGPT THE GOAT